# Entity framework 4.3 DBMigrations code first, database dependency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a code first model with db migrations working fine on a mysql .net connector 6.6.x driver.

But i was wondering if the migrations i am generating from the models are mysql specific or should i be able to migrate the same dbmigrations (including initial create script) to other databases as long as i have configured a driver and sqlgenerator for it ?

I know it somehow does use the database schema you are developing againt to generate the dbmigration steps.
Although its not clear to me why, cause it should be able to generate these totally based on the code first models.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL script generated by DB Migrations (the .sql file) cannot be run against other databases as that script will be specific for the database it was run against.

However you could still re-generate the script against a different database.  The Model is abstract, the SQL isn't (and can't be)

Comment: but it does not add any sql script files. I only have dbmigration classes that represent the patches and initial model. Should the drivers not be able to run these independent of how to dbmigration files where created?

Comment: If you are running the migrations into a database, then SQL is generated at runtime and is thus not db specific.  If you run your migrations into a SQL Script file then there will be DB specific.